# protocol buffer message to and from an XPathDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a protocol buffer message to and from an XPathDocument but it fails with an exception:
**ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Mismatched group tags detected in message**
How do I make this work?

I am using protobuf-net and my source code for reproducing it looks like this:

TestMsg.proto

```
    option optimize_for = SPEED;

//*************************
message Test {
    repeated A a = 1;
}

message A {
    required string str = 1;
}
```

Progam.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using ProtoBuf;
using TestMsg;

namespace protocolbufferserialize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            XPathDocument xmldoc = Serialize(t);
            Test t1 = Serialize(xmldoc);
        }

        public static XPathDocument Serialize(Test wro)
        {
            XPathDocument xmlDoc = null;
            Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Test>();

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(wro.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    x.Serialize(w, wro);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(memoryStream);
                }
            }
            return xmlDoc;
        }

        public static Test Serialize(XPathDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            Test t = null;
            Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Test>();

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(xmlDoc.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    x.Serialize(w, xmlDoc);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test>(memoryStream);
                }
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tried to extend use Serializer.Merge but the Test object is empty when it comes back from xml.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using ProtoBuf;
using TestMsg;

namespace TestXMLSerilizationLars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            A a = new A();
            string str = "test";
            a.str = str;
            t.a.Add(a);
            XPathDocument xmldoc = Serialize(t);
            WriteXpathDocument(xmldoc, "c:\\testmsg.xml");
            Test t1 = Serialize(xmldoc);
        }

        public static XPathDocument Serialize(Test t)
        {
            XPathDocument xmlDoc = null;
            Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Test>();

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    x.Serialize(w, t);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(memoryStream);
                }
            }
            return xmlDoc;
        }

        public static Test Serialize(XPathDocument xmlDoc)
        {
            Test t = null;

            Type type = xmlDoc.GetType();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, xmlDoc);
                // memoryStream.Close();
                Test newt = Deserialize(memoryStream.ToArray());
                return newt;
            }            
            return t;
        }

        static public Test Deserialize(byte[] Bytes)
        {
            MemoryStream SerializeStream = new MemoryStream(Bytes);
            Test NewObject = Serializer.Deserialize<Test>(SerializeStream);
            Test ObjectExist = new Test();

            if (ObjectExist == null)
            {
                return NewObject;
            }
            else
            {
                SerializeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Serializer.Merge<Test>(SerializeStream, ObjectExist);
                return ObjectExist;
            }
        }

        public static void WriteXpathDocument(XPathDocument xpathDoc, string filename)
        {
            // Create XpathNaviagtor instances from XpathDoc instance.
            XPathNavigator objXPathNav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();

            // Create XmlWriter settings instance.
            XmlWriterSettings objXmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            objXmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

            // Create disposable XmlWriter and write XML to file.
            using (XmlWriter objXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename, objXmlWriterSettings))
            {
                objXPathNav.WriteSubtree(objXmlWriter);
                objXmlWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The xml file I dump out looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>
    <A>
      <str>test</str>
    </A>
  </a>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time you use protobuf here is:

```
x.Serialize(w, xmlDoc);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
t = Serializer.Deserialize<Test>(memoryStream);
```

where you have written xml (`x` is an `XmlSerializer`), and then attempted to read it via protobuf (`Serializer.Deserialize`).

However; protobuf is not xml; it is a binary format *completely* unrelated to xml. If your intention is to deep-clone the data, you should also *serialize* with protobuf-net (`Serializer.Serialize`).

It *is* often possible to convert a *model* between the two formats, but the streams *themselves* are not swappable.